# Objects inside a loop different to outside

Tags: javascript, loops, object

The objects inside my loop have different values the the ones outside. I cant seem to find out how the value changes.

```
f = console.log
a = ["b","c"]
o ={d:1,e:2}
a.forEach(x=>{
  o.k = x
  window[x]=o;
  f("inside the loop we have "+ x + ":")
  f(window[x])
})
f("outside the loop we have b:")
f(b)
f("outside the loop we have c:")
f(c)
```

Strangely the output is:

```
inside the loop we have b: 
Object { d: 1, e: 2, k: "b" }
inside the loop we have c: 
Object { d: 1, e: 2, k: "c" }
outside the loop we have b: 
Object { d: 1, e: 2, k: "c" }
outside the loop we have c: 
Object { d: 1, e: 2, k: "c" }
```

Why did the value `b.k` change to `"c"`? If find this very strange. But obviously I don't something here.

​

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `o` is an object that gets shared. In this line:

```
a.forEach(x=>{
  o.k = x
```

In the first pass, `x` is `"b"`, so `o.k = "b"`. But then the second iteration, `x` is set to `"c"`, so `o.k = "c"`. And then there are no more loops after this.
Since the last thing that happened to `o.k` was that it got set to `"c"`, now `o` looks like the following:

```
Object { d: 1, e: 2, k: "c" }
```

That's why you see it printed like that at the end.

Answer (score 0):

object assignation in javascript happens at the reference level, not at value level.

This means that when you do `window[x] = o`, you are assigning the same reference to the object "o" to both window.b and window.c. So, when you do `o.k = x` you are changing the value "k" in the object "o" and consequently in all the references to that object. A solution for such simple objects could be creating a SHALLOW copy of o before assigning it, thus assigning the reference to a new object with the same value. This is easily achieved using the spread operator.
Try changing `window[x] = o` to `window[x] = {...o}`